# Restore files from a recycle bin, that is located on a server store of a roaming profile

Tags: windows-server-2003, roaming-profile, windows

An organization has a domain and all users have a roaming profiles.

A user deletes files from My Documents, and they appear to be in the recycle bin on the server's user profile store.

How can admin access and restore those files?

A particular computer, from where the files were put to the recycle bin is no longer available. If an admin logs in with this user profile on a different PC, the recycle bin in the profile is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a file in the profile on a server that you want access to as an administrator you can take ownership of the profile and all the files under it, give yourself the rights to access that profile and navigate the filesystem as you would any other directory. When done you change the owner of that profile folder and all sub-folders and files back to the original user.

I'm not sure if the files in the recycle bin are typically stored in the profile. The best solution if it's something important is to restore it from your backups so you don't need to mess with the ownership and permissions on the profile. I've had times where things got screwy after changing this, plus you have to make sure the user isn't accessing those files anywhere else on the network at the time.

Another method to check is to have them log in somewhere and access their profile path from their login. They have permission to access it on the server, and if you think it's in a recycle folder within the profile on the server it should get synced to another machine at login. If it's not on the workstation at login, it's not part of the profile...so emptied recycle bin means it's not in the profile. You wouldn't be able to get it back anyway.